# Doctrine query condition doesn't select desired language

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm using doctrine in my Symfony2 project. I did a query that gets all my project in a certain language, but it returns me all the language:

```
public function rechercherProjets($lang, $cat)
    {

        return $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin ('p.descriptions', 'pi') 
            ->innerJoin('p.categories', 'c')
            ->where('c.tag = :cat')
            ->andWhere('pi.langue = :lang')
            ->setParameters(array('lang'=>$lang,'cat'=>$cat))
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```

Strangely, the ->where('c.tag = :cat') works perfectly, but the ->andWhere('pi.langue = :lang') makes that when I try to display my projects in my twig template, it's really weird. Basically, I use this:

```
{% for projet in projets %}
            <article class="projet">
                <a href="{{ path('portfolio_public_projet',{'tag':projet.tag}) }}">
                    <img src="{{ asset("bundles/public/projets/vignettes/"~ projet.image) }}" alt="paranorium">
                    <h2>{{ projet.descriptions[0].nom }}</h2>
                    <div class="infoReduit">
                        <p>{{ projet.descriptions[0].descriptionCours }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="infoTotal">
                        <p>{{ projet.descriptions[0].descriptionComplete }}</p>
                        <p>{% trans %}role{% endtrans %}: {{ projet.descriptions[0].roles }}</p>
                        <p>{% trans %}technologie{% endtrans %}: {{ projet.technologie }}</p>
                        <p>{% trans %}aptitude{% endtrans %}: {{ projet.descriptions[0].aptitudesDeveloppees }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <b>{% trans %}realisation{% endtrans %} {{ projet.annee }}</b>
                </a>
            </article>   
        {% endfor %}
```

The projet.description[0] actually contains the information of my project in the first language (French) and projet.description[1] contains the information of my project in my second language (English). What I want is that my request returns me a projet.description that contains only 1 thing which is the language I asked for.

Or maybe I'm doing this the wrong way, if so, how to do it right?

Comment: Î just noticed that if I had ->select('pi.descriptionCours  as descriptionCours') in my query , it gives me the correct info, but I still wants to know why it doesn't eretrun me only the info in the correct language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `createQueryBuilder('p')` will add the select statement on p which symbolize the entity the repo is linked to.

If you want to select anything which is out of your entity's scope, then you need to use `addSelect('yourentity.attribute')` to make the selection explicit.